# Lumen FatalErrorException in RedirectResponse.php line 75: Call to a member function flashInput() on null

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, lumen-5.2

Hi I got this errors in Lumen

> FatalErrorException in RedirectResponse.php line 75:
>   Call to a member function flashInput() on null
>
> in RedirectResponse.php line 75
>
> at Application->handleShutdown() in RegistersExceptionHandlers.php line 55
>
> at Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns{closure}()

Here the code which throws the error:

```
return redirect('formular')
    ->withErrors($validator)
    ->withInput();
```

The error comes from withInput()

Answer (score 5):

The error is happening because Lumen 5.2 does not support sessions. The `withErrors()` and `withInput()` methods attempt to set values on the `session` attribute on the redirector, but the `session` attribute is null.

From the [Lumen 5.2 documentation on validation](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation):

> Lumen does not support sessions out of the box, so the `$errors` view variable that is available in every view in Laravel is not available in Lumen. The `$this->validate` helper will always return JSON responses with the relevant error messages when validation fails. If you are not building a stateless API that solely sends JSON responses, you should use the full Laravel framework.

Basically, if you're trying to use sessions, you're trying to use Lumen 5.2 in a way it was not intended. You should either be using Lumen 5.1, or using the full Laravel framework. You can read the [release notes here](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/releases#5.2.0) on the philosophy change for Lumen 5.2.