# FatalErrorException in RedirectResponse.php line 119: Call to a member function flash() on null

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I got this in Lumen:

> FatalErrorException in RedirectResponse.php line 119:
>   Call to a member function flash() on null
>
> in RedirectResponse.php line 119
>
> at Application->handleShutdown() in RegistersExceptionHandlers.php line 55
>
> at Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns{closure}()

Here the code which throws the error:

```
return redirect('formular')
    ->withErrors($validator)
    ->withInput();
```

The error comes from withErrors()

This errors belongs togehter:

[Lumen FatalErrorException in RedirectResponse.php line 75: Call to a member function flashInput() on null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35456716/lumen-fatalerrorexception-in-redirectresponse-php-line-75-call-to-a-member-func)

Comment: Can you post the validator code?

Comment: I have posted an answer on the other question. This question is a duplicate and should be closed or deleted.