# Calling Redirect facade from Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I would like to call Redirect facade inside the Lumen controller. So I included Redirect facade:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
```

and added to app.php

```
class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect', 'Redirect');
```

However, when I call Redirect inside my controller:

```
 Redirect::to('login')
```

I get an error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::to()
```

What  is wrong here? How to actually call Redirect facade from Lumen ?

Comment: May I ask why you need the Facade? Not just using [the documented way](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#redirects)

Comment: I am just following a tutorial, https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-and-easy-laravel-login-authentication . How would I call withErros() and withInput() as shown in tutorial, but without the Facade?

Comment: Well my first thought is you are following a tutorial for L4.1 which is quite out dated if you are using Lumen. Lumen (if you are using the new one) is based off L5.2. You may want to look for a more up to date tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

It seems from the comments you are following an outdated tutorial. For Lumen and newer versions of Laravel, redirects are done slightly differently and you dont need the Facade.

[From the documentation](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#redirects) redirects are done like this:

```
return redirect('login');
```

You mentioned in your comments you would like to use `withErrors()` and my previous edit suggested you could. However, thanks to @patricus for pointing out it looks like Lumen have removed session support in 5.2 therefore `withErrors()` wont work unfortunately.

Explanation for which can be found a previous [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35456716/lumen-fatalerrorexception-in-redirectresponse-php-line-75-call-to-a-member-func/35464802#35464802)

Comment: Lumen 5.2 doesn't support sessions, so `withErrors()` is not going to work. May want to check out [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35456716/lumen-fatalerrorexception-in-redirectresponse-php-line-75-call-to-a-member-func/35464802#35464802).

Comment: Well you learn something new everyday. Im using 5.1 so I have sessions and i didnt spot they had removed it, thanks.